# redis-server getting stuck when using daemonize no on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, redis, daemon, upstart

I'm using this link to configure redis with upstart:
https://gist.github.com/bdotdub/714533

I have set:

```
daemonize no
```

in redis.conf that's being used to start the server. Here's my redis upstart script:

```
description "redis server"

start on runlevel [23]
stop on shutdown
respawn

exec sudo -u redis /usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

but now whenever I do:

```
sudo service redis-server start
```

or

```
sudo service redis-server stop
```

the command gets stuck. I tried running the command manually:

```
sudo -u redis /usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

and it works perfectly fine (in foreground as expected). Can someone help me with the setup. Tailing the logs indicated that `sudo service` command is not even starting the server.